# Fail when required JsonProperty is missing or null

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I have a class User with 2 fields: required `id` and optional `name`. I use lombok and jackson (version 2.12) annotations.

```
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@ToString
public class User {
  @JsonProperty(required = true)
  private String id;

  private String name;
}
```

I try to deserialise a json and expect it to fail as the `test` doesn't have the required property `id`:

```
String test = "{\"name\":\"blablabla\"}";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = objectMapper.readValue(test, User.class);
```

I found that it should be working if I add a constructor with jackson annotation `@JsonCreator`.

Is it possible without changing the `User` class?

Comment: I don't think so. What happens is that the mapper fetches the properties from your JSON document and assigns them to the classes attributes. Because there is no id in your JSON object its setter won't be called at all and thus no check can't be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use `@JsonCreator` implementation as didn't find the answer. That's how `User` class looks like now:

```
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@ToString
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @JsonCreator
    public static User create(
            @JsonProperty(value = "id", required = true) String id,
            @JsonProperty("name") String name
    ) {
        return new User(id, name);
    }
}
```